# curl retry on timeout

Tags: curl, timeout

I've written a shell script that has a function like this:

```
function getpage {
        echo $1
        curl -O "http://www.example.com/$1" -b cookie.txt -s
}
```

The problem is if the website times out then that page will be skipped, I need it to re-try if it times out (I will also be putting in a 60 second timeout).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `--retry <num>` for forced retries. An alternate way is to add `-w http_code` to see what the return code is...if it's not 200 then try again.

Comment: now why dint I think of that, timeout value of 10 seconds with 50 retries (I highly doubt it will ever need more than 3 though)

Comment: Is there a way to retry when the error is host unreachable or connection refused?

Comment: you could use:
     --writeout {http_code}
And parse the result. Curl will return 0 if unable to connect, else the status code.

Comment: @jrwren you can add --retry-connrefused